# How can I upload an updated LaTeX package?

Tags: packages, update

I've modified a LaTeX package I created some years ago.
Now I would like to upload the modified package. I tried to use http://www.ctan.org/upload, but I don't understand to which subdirectory to update it.

Any help?

Comment: just make  zip file that contains your package and a README.txt then navigate to the ctan page for your package and click upload the form will then be pre-filled in with the existing ctan location and version etc, so just update the version number attach the zip and submit. If you are using a different email then leave some notes in the the Notes box telling teh ctan maintainers that you are the original author

Comment: @David Carlisle thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just make zip file that contains your package and a README.txt then navigate to the ctan page for your package and click upload the form will then be pre-filled in with the existing ctan location and version etc, so just update the version number attach the zip and submit. If you are using a different email then leave some notes in the the Notes box telling the ctan maintainers that you are the original author